# Generic types with generic constraines

Tags: c#, generics

I've following types:

```
public interface IContainer<in TKey, out TValue>
{
    TValue Resolve(TKey key);
}

public interface IBuilder<out TContainer, in TKey, out TValue> where 
TContainer : IContainer<TKey, TValue>
{
    TContainer Build();
}

public interface IRegister<in TBuilder, TKey, TValue> where TBuilder : 
IBuilder<IContainer<TKey, TValue>, TKey, TValue>
{
    void Register(TBuilder builder);
}

public interface IServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainer<TService, in 
TServiceMessageHandler> 
    : IContainer<TServiceMessageHandler, ECommand>
    where TServiceMessageHandler : class, IMessageHandler<TService>
{

}

public interface IServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainerBuilder<TService, in 
TServiceMessageHandler, out             TServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainer> 
    : IBuilder<TServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainer, TServiceMessageHandler, 
ECommand>
    where TServiceMessageHandler : class, IMessageHandler<TService>
    where TServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainer : 
IServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainer<TService, TServiceMessageHandler>
{
    void Register<TServiceMessageHandlerType>(ECommand command) 
        where TServiceMessageHandlerType : TServiceMessageHandler;
}

public interface IServiceMessageHandlerTypeRegister<
    TService, 
    TServiceMessageHandler, 
    TServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainer, 
    in TServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainerBuilder> 
    : IRegister<TServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainerBuilder, 
TServiceMessageHandler, ECommand>
    where TServiceMessageHandler : class, IMessageHandler<TService>
    where TServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainer 
    : IServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainer<TService, TServiceMessageHandler> 
    where TServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainerBuilder 
    : IServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainerBuilder<TService, 
TServiceMessageHandler, TServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainer>
{

}
```

And i really can not get, why constrain for TServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainerBuilder is not good here?

cause IServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainerBuilder

is IBuilder

and IServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainer
is IContainer

Do you have any ideas what can be wrong here?

If i add contrain:
where TServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainerBuilder 
        : IServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainerBuilder, 
        IBuilder, TServiceMessageHandler, ECommand>

it works

but it's really not that what i need

EDIT:
the compile time error is:

Error   CS0314  The type 'TServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainerBuilder' cannot be used as type parameter 'TBuilder' in the generic type or method 'IRegister'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainerBuilder' to 'Patterns.DependencyInjection.Builder.IBuilder, TServiceMessageHandler, DataTransmissionServices.Enums.ECommand>'.

Is something connected with co- and contra-variance?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not good"? Do you mean this causes a compile-time error? If so, please include the error in the question. Also, if you could reduce the number of types involved in the question at all, that would definitely help to make it clearer.

Comment: I added compile time error.
I think i can not reduce number of types, casue all types here can be a reason of a error

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not related to co- or contra-variance. It is related to constraints on generic parameters.

The constratin for TServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainerBuilder is going to `IBuilder<out TContainer, in TKey, out TValue> where TContainer : IContainer<TKey, TValue>`

but when you inherit `IServiceMessageHandlerTypeRegister` from

```
IRegister<TServiceMessageHandlerTypeContainerBuilder,TServiceMessageHandler, ECommand>
```

the constraint goes to IBuilder, TKey, TValue>.
Because IBuilder, TKey, TValue> can not be converted to IBuilder you are getting compile error.